# Deploying application in Liferay (Liferay running as a war file on JBOSS EAP 6.4)

Tags: jboss, liferay, portlet, web.xml

I'm having trouble deploying an application within Liferay while Liferay is running on JBoss EAP 6.4. The setup is necessary because this a portlet we are producing through WSRP (also we've tried JBoss Portal/Gatein but it wouldn't work for our setup).
Steps taken:

- Deploy Liferay 6.2CE GA4 war file on JBoss EAP 6.4
- Install Liferay WSRP portal
- Deploy our portlet through Liferay GUI - "Manage Apps" -> "Install"

`server.log`:

```
12:49:38,979 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MyApp.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyApp.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "MyApp.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018014: Failed to parse XML descriptor "/C:/Users/580085/Desktop/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/deployments/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/web.xml" at [154,3]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:116)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[154,3]
Message: Unexpected element '{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee}filter' encountered
at org.jboss.metadata.parser.util.MetaDataElementParser.unexpectedElement(MetaDataElementParser.java:109)
at org.jboss.metadata.parser.servlet.ServletMetaDataParser.parse(ServletMetaDataParser.java:126)
at org.jboss.metadata.parser.servlet.WebCommonMetaDataParser.parse(WebCommonMetaDataParser.java:102)
at org.jboss.metadata.parser.servlet.WebMetaDataParser.parse(WebMetaDataParser.java:175)
at org.jboss.metadata.parser.servlet.WebMetaDataParser.parse(WebMetaDataParser.java:55)
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:91)
... 6 more
12:49:38,995 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014612: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApp.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApp.war\".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"MyApp.war\"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018014: Failed to parse XML descriptor \"/C:/Users/1234/Desktop/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/deployments/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/web.xml\" at [154,3]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[154,3]
Message: Unexpected element '{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee}filter' encountered"}}
12:49:39,026 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment MyApp.war (runtime-name: MyApp.war) in 27ms
12:49:39,026 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1)
JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."MyApp.war".PARSE
```

My `web.xml` header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>MyApp</display-name>
```

Line 154 of `web.xml`:

`<init-param>
    <param-name>property-name</param-name>
    <param-value>ApplicationResources.properties</param-value>
</init-param>`

Even if I remove the `<init-param>` definition the parse error still presents itself. I suspect it may be a schema-related issue. Any tips are appreciated.

EDIT: Also, this portlet app ran correctly on Websphere previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing `<filter>` tags apparently in my web.xml. I had none. I copied them over from an included liferay `web.xml` and pasted them right under my `<context-param>` definitions.

`<filter>
        <filter-name>Invoker Filter - ERROR</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>dispatcher</param-name>
            <param-value>ERROR</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Invoker Filter - FORWARD</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>dispatcher</param-name>
            <param-value>FORWARD</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Invoker Filter - INCLUDE</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>dispatcher</param-name>
            <param-value>INCLUDE</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Invoker Filter - REQUEST</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>dispatcher</param-name>
            <param-value>REQUEST</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Invoker Filter - ERROR</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Invoker Filter - FORWARD</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Invoker Filter - INCLUDE</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Invoker Filter - REQUEST</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>`